# Upload file to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, select, upload

I wrote a program that saves the data series in a txt file and I want to upload that file to firebase.
My problem is that I cannot choose the file in which the data is saved to be uploaded to Firebase
Please guide me with the source code or...

Comment: Hi there, you can try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.